# NHibernate Mapping Exception: invalid child element

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm having a problem with NHibernate and the mapping file when I try to save my drink object in my MVC application. My mapping file is an embedded resource and my hibernate.cfg.xml is copy always.

Here are my class.cs:

```
namespace FrancosPoS.DBMapping {

    public class drink {
        public drink() { }
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        public virtual string type { get; set; }
        public virtual string price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My XML mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" namespace="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="drink" table="drink" lazy="true" >
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="identity" />
            <column name="id" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="true" />
        </id>
        <property name="type">
            <column name="type" sql-type="varchar(25)" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="price">
            <column name="price" sql-type="varchar(8)" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

By the way, the connection opens and close fine if I don't try to save it on the database.

Here is my Solution Explorer:

[Solution Explorer Image](http://db.tt/BD4D4fyA)

And here is the error that is driving me nuts:

```
"Error: NHibernate.MappingException: FrancosPoS.DBMapping.drink.hbm.xml(6,8): XML validation error: The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'column' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'column' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in node id, it does not have a  child, remove that node and it will simply be like this:

```
<id name="id">
        <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

the column's name is specified in id node, and you dont have to tell column has "not-null" constraint since id columns are always required

Also, in this line of your xml mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping assembly="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" namespace="FrancosPoS.DBMapping" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
```

"assembly" attribute seems to be wrong, it should be the name of your assembly (which i'm almost sure is "FrancosPos").

Comment: Uhmmm, I tried but now it gives me this error:

    "Error: NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: FrancosPoS.DBMapping.drink.hbm.xml ---> NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class FrancosPoS.DBMapping.drink, FrancosPoS.DBMapping not found ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FrancosPoS.DBMapping' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n

Maybe because the commit file is on a different path than the xml.

What can I do!?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man!

You are right, the assembly is just FrancosPoS.

Sincerely,